# Removing duplicate SQL records to permit a unique key

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have a table ('sales') in a MYSQL DB which should rightfully have had a unique constraint enforced to prevent duplicates. To first remove the dupes and set the constraint is proving a bit tricky.

Table structure (simplified):

- 'id (unique, autoinc)'
- product_id

The goal is to enforce uniqueness for product_id. The de-duping policy I want to apply is to remove all duplicate records except the most recently created, eg: the highest id.

Or to put another way, I would like to delete only duplicate records, excluding the ids matched by the following query whilst also preserving the existing non-duped records:

```
select id 
  from sales s  
inner join (select product_id, 
                   max(id) as maxId 
              from sales 
          group by product_id 
            having count(product_id)  > 1) groupedByProdId on s.product_id 
                                                          and s.id = groupedByProdId.maxId
```

I've struggled with this on two fronts - writing the query to select the correct records to delete and then also the constraint in MYSQL where a subselect FROM clause of a DELETE cannot reference the same table from which data is being removed.

I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759672/how-to-remove-duplicate-records-in-a-table) answer and it seemed to deal with the subject, but seem specific to sql-server, though I wouldn't rule this question out from duplicating another.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In reply to your comment, here's a query that works in MySQL:

```
delete YourTable
from YourTable
inner join YourTable yt2
on YourTable.product_id = yt2.product_id
and YourTable.id < yt2.id
```

This would only remove duplicate rows.  The `inner join` will filter out the latest row for each product, even if no other rows for the same product exist.

P.S. If you try to alias the table after `FROM`, MySQL requires you to specify the name of the database, like:

```
delete <DatabaseName>.yt
from YourTable yt
inner join YourTable yt2
on yt.product_id = yt2.product_id
and yt.id < yt2.id;
```

Comment: What to do if I `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('db'.'AnotherTable', CONSTRAINT 'AnotherTable_fk' FOREIGN KEY ('YourTable.product_id') REFERENCES 'YourTable' ('product_id') ON DELETE NO ACTION)`?

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps use `ALTER IGNORE TABLE ... ADD UNIQUE KEY`. 
For example:

```
describe sales;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| product_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

select * from sales;
+----+------------+
| id | product_id |
+----+------------+
|  1 |          1 | 
|  2 |          1 | 
|  3 |          2 | 
|  4 |          3 | 
|  5 |          3 | 
|  6 |          2 | 
+----+------------+

ALTER IGNORE TABLE sales ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1(product_id), ORDER BY id DESC; 
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 3  Warnings: 0


select * from sales;
+----+------------+
| id | product_id |
+----+------------+
|  6 |          2 | 
|  5 |          3 | 
|  2 |          1 | 
+----+------------+
```

See this [pythian post](http://www.pythian.com/news/1164/adding-a-unique-constraint-on-a-table-with-duplicate-data/) for more information.

Note that the `id`s end up in reverse order. I don't think this matters, since order of the `id`s should not matter in a database (as far as I know!). If this displeases you however, the post linked to above shows a way to solve this problem too. However, it involves creating a temporary table which requires more hard drive space than the in-place method I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I might do the following in sql-server to eliminate the duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM Sales
FROM Sales
    INNER JOIN Sales b ON Sales.product_id = b.product_id AND Sales.id < b.id
```

It looks like the analogous [delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) statement for mysql might be:

```
DELETE FROM Sales 
USING Sales
    INNER JOIN Sales b ON Sales.product_id = b.product_id AND Sales.id < b.id
```

Comment: Yah, I was trying it out when you posted your revised answer following my comment, Andomar. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is easier to solve with CTEs and Ranking functions, however, you should be able to do something like the following to solve your problem:

```
Delete Sales
Where Exists(
            Select 1
            From Sales As S2
            Where S2.product_id = Sales.product_id
                And S2.id > Sales.Id
            Having Count(*) > 0
            )
```