# How to Delete Duplicate record from the sql table except one from duplicate records?

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove duplicate records in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759672/how-to-remove-duplicate-records-in-a-table)

I'm having one table which contains one of the column with ProjectID which has duplicate records in the table. And table having Primary key column. I want to keep one record & delete the rest duplications.
Following query is to find the total number of duplicate records with the no. of occurrences-

```
SELECT ProjectID, 
COUNT(ProjectID) AS NumOccurrences
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ProjectID
HAVING ( COUNT(ProjectID) > 1 )
```

How to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(
  select row_number() over(partition by ProjectID order by ProjectID) as rn
  from MyTable
)
delete cte
where rn > 1
```

Comment: I tried your query, it works fine as what i want but it gives following error when parsing query - `The following errors were encountered while parsing the contents of the SQL pane:

The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported`

Comment: @Priyanka – I don't understand. It runs fine but you get an error when parsing? How do you parse? With what?

Comment: @Priyanka – Now I see. It's the "SQL pane". I don't think the visual designer in Microsoft Management Studio can handle row_number or perhaps not even a Common Table Expression.

Comment: @ Mikael Eriksson: I's parsing the query through VS2010's server explorer. But i've tested on the Microsoft SQL Server Management studio & it works fine. But if i use this query in the application which is developed in vs2010 then whether i've to face same problem or not?

Comment: @Priyanka – I have never used VS2010. There is no problem with the query. That should be safe to use. I think you have issues with some graphical designer/query part in VS2010. If you google the error message you will see that others had similar problems.